# How can i reshape this numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have and array like this :

```py
[[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]]
```

When i shape to this array it gives `(2,)`

I tried `reshape(-1)` method but i did not work. I want to reshape this array into:

```py
[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]
```

How can i convert that? I would be glad if you help.

Comment: Is this a list or a numpy array ? It would also help if you provide the initial shape of your array.

Comment: @IbrahimSherifYahia it is numpy.ndarray

Comment: What are `a`, `b`, etc.  As `@uniQ` shows, if they are single characters (or numbers) , the result is an array with shape (1,3,2), not the (2,) that you claim.  If it really was (1,3,2) shape, you could just index on the first dimension and get a (3,2) array.  That indexing would work even if it was a nested list instead of array.

Comment: You say `reshape(-1)` doesn't work.  "doesn't work" is not very informative - to you or us.  What was wrong?  An error message?  A wrong result?  Don't just throw that result away; try to learn from it.

Comment: I'm gonna do next time. Thank you! @hpaulj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chars_list = [[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]]
chars_list_one = []
for element in chars_list:
    for element_one in element:
        chars_list_one.append(element_one)
print(chars_list_one)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`numpy.squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) function.

```py
a = np.array([[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"]]])
print(a.shape)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
(1, 3, 2)
[[['a' 'b']
  ['c' 'd']
  ['e' 'f']]]
```

```
b = a.squeeze(0)
print(b.shape)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
(3, 2)
[['a' 'b']
 ['c' 'd']
 ['e' 'f']]
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me now [([[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]])]. And it gives to me ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.squeeze` method.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]])
a.squeeze()
```

Output:

```py
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['c', 'd'],
       ['e', 'f']], dtype='<U1')
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me now [([[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]])]. And it gives to me ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)